# How to serialise a JSON string inside a JSON object

Tags: jquery, json, reactjs, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an object that contains a property "Data". This property holds additional, meta data in Json format.

However, I now need to send the entire object down to a web page as a Json string. I'm using .Net Core 2.0 with the following code

```
var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
content = content.Replace("\\r\\n", "");
return View("Index", content);
```

In StartUp.ConfigureService I also have the following

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
```

Unfortunately, I'm now getting

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 3159
    at JSON.parse ()

How do I ensure that my Data property isn't seen as Json until it's actually needed (at which case I'll use JQuery to deserialise the bit I need)

My Json string that is being returned looks like so

```
{content:"this", foo: "bar", data:"["array1","array2","array3"]" }
```

Obviously I have quote issues.....

Thanks

Comment: Maybe don't do `content = content.Replace("\\r\\n", "");` ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue.

I just needed to escape the double quotes in the data property Json so that the complete Json returned as such

```
{content:"this", foo: "bar", data:"[\"array1\",\"array2\",\"array3\"]" }
```